# Unbale to pass correct value to api in react frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a problem passing the correct value to my API call.
if I were to send query = "were" I am only able to send "e" only the last word I type

This is the input tag in which I ought to type a search query

```
<input
    type="text"
    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
    placeholder="Search..."
    className="input input-sm input-bordered input-secondary "
    style={{
        color: "white",
       "::placeholder": { color: "white" },
    }}
/>
```

and here is the logic for catching the value and sending an api call

```
  const [search, setSearch] = useState({});

  function handleInputChange(e) {
    // Get the input value
    const searchValue = e.target.value;
    const val = { _q: searchValue };
    setSearch(val);
  }

  const fetchSuggestions = async (query) => {
    try {
      // Replace this URL with your actual API endpoint for fetching suggestions
      const response = await fetchProductsByFilters(query);
      const data = response.data.products;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching suggestions:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSuggestions(search);
    console.log(search);
  }, [search]);
```

the console.log in the above useEffect hook provide the correct query for e.g - {_q: 'were'}, Consider my api calling

```
export function fetchProductsByFilters(
  filter,
  sort,
  pagination,
  admin,
  search
) {
  // filter = {"category":["smartphone","laptops"]}
  // sort = {_sort:"price",_order="desc"}
  // pagination = {_page:1,_limit=10}
  // search = {_q:"searchQuery"}

  let queryString = "";
  for (let key in filter) {
    const categoryValues = filter[key];
    if (categoryValues.length) {
      const lastCategoryValue = categoryValues[categoryValues.length - 1];
      queryString += `${key}=${lastCategoryValue}&`;
    }
  }
  for (let key in search) {
    queryString += `${key}=${search[key]}&`;
  }
  for (let key in sort) {
    queryString += `${key}=${sort[key]}&`;
  }
  for (let key in pagination) {
    queryString += `${key}=${pagination[key]}&`;
  }
  if (admin) {
    queryString += `admin=true`;
  }

  console.log(queryString);

  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    //TODO: we will not hard-code server URL here
    console.log(queryString, 2);
    const response = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:8080/products?" + queryString
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    const totalItems = await response.headers.get("X-Total-Count");
    resolve({ data: { products: data, totalItems: +totalItems } });
  });
}
```

In this the query string from the console.log(queryString) I get is _q=e , only the last letter, I type not the full word. Why is that can you help identify the root cause and modify the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem here the this function

```
export function fetchProductsByFilters(
  filter,
  sort,
  pagination,
  admin,
  search
)
```

You have 5 parameters for the function and the top most is filter, and when you are call this function, you are simply doing this `fetchProductsByFilters(query);` which is not correct if you want to pass values to the `search` parameter. as javascript will assume it to be the first parameter which is `filter` so from your code it is taking the last value of the query. which is correct.

Now to fix this you can do 2 things either pass undefined values for all other parameters like this `fetchProductsByFilters(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, query)`
or you can modify the code of the function to have the parameters in brackets

```
export function fetchProductsByFilters({
  filter,
  sort,
  pagination,
  admin,
  search
})
```

this will give you autocomplete when you add parameters to the function, so when calling you can simply do `fetchProductsByFilters({ search: query })`.

This will solve your problem.